# Why to execute SQL query takes so much time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query you can see example below:

```
SELECT TOP(50000)* FROM
[Database].[dbo].[Table] WHERE Column
IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Column2 DESC
```

To execute it takes **2 min 21 sec**, in total records about **350K**

Columns types

```
ID int
Column1 nvarchar(50)
Column2 nvarchar(250)
Column3 datetime
Column4 nvarchar(1000)
Column5 nvarchar(1000)
Column6 nvarchar(50)
```

In my opinion it takes to long. can anyone suggest me how to improve performance?
Or maybe someone knows what can be the root cause?

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Answer (score 3):

Several things:

- Do you have an index on the "column" where you filter? The column number is not in your question
- It may not help, you have SELECT *
- Does the index use column2?
- Have you tried separately?

Design

- Do you need nvarchar? Make it varchar

Basically, you are returning around 1/7 of the table so any index on the filter column may be ignored, coupled with SELECT *. An index on column2 may help to avoid intermediate sorting.

Edit:

With 3 columns, you can make it [covering](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) (as marc_s' comment)

Comment: Ok I changed my columns types to varchar and made it smaller. the same query takes now 1 min, 14 sec.Thank you  Is there anything else I can improve to make it faster?

Comment: Also instead of * all I changed to select 3 columns and now it takes no more than 25 sec on the same query

Comment: @Bogdan: if you had an index that would have these three columns you need in it - possibly as INCLUDE columns - then you might see another big boost in performance

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a large amount of data - network IO may easily account for the time taken.

You may also missing an index on your `column2` column, which can cause a table scan instead of an index seek (expensive vs cheap operation).

Answer (score 0):

Have you put an index on column2 (the one used for order by)?

Comment: Yes I have index on that column

USE [Database]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ID] ON [dbo].[Table] 
(
 [ID] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: That sounds like an index on column 'id' and not on 'column2' or 'column' (the one you filter on, which isn't in the table description.)